# What does mean by 'out of range offset' and when does 'only the first character of an assigned string is used'?

Tags: php, string, null, byte, offset

I'm using **PHP 7.2.2**

I'm not able to understand following paragraph taken from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

> **Warning** Writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces.
>   Non-integer types are converted to integer. Illegal offset type emits
>   **E_NOTICE**. Only the first character of an assigned string is used. As
>   of PHP 7.1.0, assigning an empty string throws a fatal error.
>   Formerly, it assigned a NULL byte.

I've following doubts/questions in my mind regarding the above paragraph :

1. What does exactly mean by 'out of range offset' here?
2. Whose non-integer types are converted to integer. Is it an offset or a character from a string under consideration whose type conversion is going to happen?
3. What does exactly mean by 'Illegal offset type'?
4. When does 'only the first character of an assigned string is used'?
5. What does mean bye the last sentence 'Formerly, it assigned a NULL byte.'? Specifically what does mean by NULL byte?

Can someone please answer all of my doubts/questions in an easy to understand language with suitable working code example?

Comment: The *range* for the word "badgers" is 0-6 (the indexes of the characters) so if you attempted to add "!" at `badgers{12}` it would pad the string with spaces, something like `badgers     !` (with 5 spaces between the 's' and the '!')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the manual is in reference to treating strings as an array of characters.

- "out of range" offset means an integer index that is at a position longer than the string itself currently is, e.g. `$x = "foo"; $x[10] = 'o';`  results in `$x` becoming `foo       o`
- If a non-integer index value is used, the index value is converted to an integer before the index of the string is accessed, e.g. `$x = "foo"; $y = $x[true];` results in `$y` taking the value of `$x[1]` - `o`
- Illegal offset types are anything that couldn't normally be used as an array offset, e.g. `class Foo() {}` - indexing a string with `$x[new Foo()];` raises a warning
- The first chracter piece means that if you attempt to assign a string to the index of an existing string, only the first character of the assigned string will be used, e.g. `$x = "foo"; $x[0] = "hi";` results in `$x` becoming `hoo`;
- Assigning a string a value of empty string at an index now results in an error rather than assigning the "null" byte `\0`, e.g. `$x[0] = ''`
  will fatal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a string for example: `$string = 'word';`

In PHP, a string is a byte array. You can refer to specific characters (bytes) in the string by their numeric index. An offset is in range if it is between `0` (first character) and `strlen($string) - 1` (last character).

This example iterates the characters in the string, using indexes 0 through 3.

```
$len = strlen($string);

for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $char = $string[$i];
    var_dump($i, $char);
}
```

An out of range offset is any index beyond strlen - 1. This code will generate a notice:

```
$char = $string[4];
var_dump($char);    // string ''
```

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4

Using a non-integer type as the index converts the type to an integer. The string `foo` (an illegal offset type) in this example will be converted to `0`, so the first character of the string will be replaced.

```
$string['foo'] = 'c';
var_dump($string); // string 'cord'
```

If you try to assign a string with more than one character, only its first character will be used, and if you try to assign to an index beyond the end of the word, the interstitial indexes will be filled with spaces.

```
$string[5] = 'something';
var_dump($string);         // string 'cord s'
```